# Frida new a anonymous class object and hook its method?

Tags: javascript, java, android, reverse-engineering, frida

Java code I want to hook

```java
package com.test.testapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public abstract class TXOut extends WebView {
    public TXOut(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    private class TXIn implements Runnable {
        String a;
        ValueCallback b;

        TXIn(String str) {
            this.a = str;
        }

        private void b() {
            int temp = 0;
            temp = temp + 3;
        }

        public void run() {}
    }
}
```

Now I want to hook **TXOut.TXIn.b** using Frida, and exucute evaluateJavascript method inside, this method require a callback method to receive result, so I have to new a anonymous class object, and I need to do this in Frida.

After Frida injected, **TXOut.TXIn.b** should behaviour like this

```java
        private void b() {
            int temp = 0;
            temp = temp + 3;
            TXOut.this.evaluateJavascript(
                    "(function() { return ('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>'); })();",
                    new ValueCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                            print(html);
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Here's my frida javascript code
I want to new a anonymous class object, and hook this object's onReceiveValue method, and get its html argument.
But I don't know how to code it.
Can anybody help me, thanks in advance.

```
var TXOut_TXIn_class = Java.use('TXOut$TXIn');
var TXOut_TXIn_class_b = TXOut_TXIn_class.b.overload();
TXOut_TXIn_class_b.implementation = function () 
{
    var returnValue = TXOut_TXIn_class_b.apply(this, arguments);
    //new ValueCallback<String>() and hook onReceiveValue method and print html argument
    //Don't know how to write it here
    return returnValue;
}
```